# What is the correct way to close the mongo connection using spring-mongo?

Tags: spring, mongodb, tomcat7, spring-mongo

I am using spring-mongo in my webapp. When I undeploy my application in Tomcat7, there is a memory leak. I suspect that it might be the Mongo object that I didn't explicitly close. I would like to know what is the correct way (and location) to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
@Component
public class MongoDBManager {

  @Autowired
  Mongo mongo;

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    mongo.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I discovered that the leak was from the Quartz scheduler which had to be stopped. Your solution helped me to shut it down correctly. Thank you !

Comment: Also if you are using a SimpleMongoDbFactory remember to simpleMongoDbFactory.destroy();

Comment: can i place this in controller?