# Restart/Reload Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

Within my project, I am using a property placeholder to read a property file, containing the configuration for my database connection. During my initial setup and reconfiguration at some point later I want to be able to change the details of the database host.

I tried to use the refresh() method called on the current application context, but somehow the Spring Data Beans are not reloaded and I am getting an IllegalStateException issued by Spring Data:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
Exception report: Message: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: open description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. exception: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
root cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: open
    org.bson.util.Assertions.isTrue(Assertions.java:36)
    com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:408)
    com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.update(DBCollectionImpl.java:263)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:191)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:975)
    com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:934)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$10.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:950)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:410)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.saveDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:945)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:885)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:833)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:73)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2987.save(Unknown Source)
    de.steilerdev.myVerein.server.controller.InitController.initSuperAdmin(InitController.java:158)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
```

Unfortunately I am not very confident with beans and their lifecycle, so I need help reloading the appropriate bean. I would also be okay with the possibility to restart the Spring application itself, even though it would be an expensive operation. Since it is only needed very rarely I would be okay with the costs of that.

I am not sure which parts of the code you need, but here is a link to the Github repository. (Sorry for the poor documentation, still at the beginning of the project)

Thanks!

---

Edit: Some classes involved in the process:

[de.steilerdev.myVerein.server.controller.InitController](https://github.com/steilerDev/myVerein/blob/master/Code/Server/src/main/java/de/steilerdev/myVerein/server/controller/InitController.java) (Receiving the related request, storing the settings to my SettingsRepository)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/init")
public class InitController
{
    @Autowired
    private SettingsRepository settingsRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DivisionRepository divisionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "settings")
    public ResponseEntity<String> initSettings(@RequestParam String clubName,
                                               @RequestParam String databaseHost,
                                               @RequestParam String databasePort,
                                               @RequestParam String databaseUser,
                                               @RequestParam String databasePassword,
                                               @RequestParam String databaseCollection,
                                               @RequestParam String rememberMeTokenKey,
                                               Locale locale)
    {
        logger.debug("Starting initial configuration");
        if(!settingsRepository.isInitSetup())
        {
            logger.warn("An initial setup API was used, even though the system is already configured.");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.settings.notAllowed", null, "You are not allowed to perform this action at the moment", locale), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else if(clubName.isEmpty() || rememberMeTokenKey.isEmpty())
        {
            logger.warn("The club name or remember me key is not present");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.settings.noKeyOrName", null, "The club name and remember me key is required", locale), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else
        {
            int databasePortInt = 27017;
            if(databaseHost.isEmpty())
            {
                logger.warn("The database host is empty, using default value.");
                databaseHost = "localhost";
            }
            if(databasePort.isEmpty())
            {
                logger.warn("The database port is empty, using default value.");
                databasePort = "27017";
            } else
            {
                try
                {
                    databasePortInt = Integer.parseInt(databasePort);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    logger.warn("The database port seems not to be a number " + databasePort);
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.settings.dbPortNoNumber", null, "The database port needs to be a number", locale), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }
            if(databaseCollection.isEmpty())
            {
                logger.warn("The database collection name is empty, using default value");
                databaseCollection = "myVerein";
            }

            if(!mongoIsAvailable(databaseHost, databasePortInt, databaseUser, databasePassword, databaseCollection))
            {
                logger.warn("The stated MongoDB is not available");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.settings.mongoNotAvailable", null, "The stated MongoDB is not available", locale), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            try
            {
                logger.debug("Temporarily storing information");
                settingsRepository.setClubName(clubName);
                settingsRepository.setDatabaseHost(databaseHost);
                settingsRepository.setDatabasePort(databasePort);
                settingsRepository.setDatabaseUser(databaseUser);
                settingsRepository.setDatabasePassword(databasePassword);
                settingsRepository.setDatabaseName(databaseCollection);
                settingsRepository.setRememberMeKey(rememberMeTokenKey);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                logger.warn("Unable to save settings.");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.settings.savingSettingsError", null, "Unable to save settings, please try again", locale), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.settings.savingSettingsSuccess", null, "Successfully saved settings", locale), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "superAdmin")
    public ResponseEntity<String> initSuperAdmin(@RequestParam String firstName,
                                                 @RequestParam String lastName,
                                                 @RequestParam String email,
                                                 @RequestParam String password,
                                                 @RequestParam String passwordRe,
                                                 Locale locale)
    {
        if(!settingsRepository.isInitSetup())
        {
            logger.warn("An initial setup API was used, even though the system is already configured.");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.admin.notAllowed", null, "You are not allowed to perform this action at the moment", locale), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else if(firstName.isEmpty() || lastName.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || passwordRe.isEmpty())
        {
            logger.warn("A required parameter of the super admin is empty or missing during initial configuration");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.admin.missingParameter", null, "A required parameter is empty or missing", locale), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else if(!password.equals(passwordRe))
        {
            logger.warn("The password and the re-typed password do not match!");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.admin.passwordMatchError", null, "The password and the re-typed password do not match", locale), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else
        {
            logger.debug("Creating a new initial user.");
            User superAdmin = new User();
            superAdmin.setFirstName(firstName);
            superAdmin.setLastName(lastName);
            superAdmin.setEmail(email);
            superAdmin.setPassword(password);

            logger.debug("Creating a new initial root division.");
            Division rootDivision = new Division(settingsRepository.getClubName(), null, superAdmin, null);

            //Saving changes and restarting context
            try
            {
                settingsRepository.setInitSetup(false);
                //This call is restarting the application.
                settingsRepository.saveSettings(superAdmin);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                logger.warn("Unable to save settings.");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.admin.savingSettingsError", null, "Unable to save settings, please try again", locale), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }

            try
            {
                userRepository.save(superAdmin);
                divisionRepository.save(rootDivision);
            } catch (ConstraintViolationException e)
            {
                logger.warn("A database constraint was violated while saving the new super admin.");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.admin.constraintViolation", null, "A database constraint was violated while saving the new super admin", locale), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(messageSource.getMessage("init.message.admin.savingAdminSuccess", null, "Successfully saved the new super admin. The settings are now being saved and the application is restarted.", locale) , HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    private boolean mongoIsAvailable(String databaseHost, int databasePort, String databaseUser, String databasePassword, String databaseCollection)
    {
        logger.debug("Creating mongo client to test connection");
        List<MongoCredential> credential = null;
        MongoClient mongoClient = null;
        if(!databaseUser.isEmpty() && !databasePassword.isEmpty())
        {
            credential = Arrays.asList(MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(databaseUser, databaseCollection, databasePassword.toCharArray()));
        }

        try
        {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(databaseHost, databasePort),credential);

            //Checking if connection REALLY works
            List<String> databases = mongoClient.getDatabaseNames();
            if(databases == null)
            {
                logger.warn("The list of databases is null");
                return false;
            } else if(databases.isEmpty())
            {
                logger.info("The databases are empty");
                return true;
            } else
            {
                logger.debug("The database connection seems okay.");
                return true;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            logger.warn("Unable to resolve mongoDB host: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (MongoException e)
        {
            logger.warn("Unable to receive list of present databases: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally
        {
            if(mongoClient != null)
            {
                mongoClient.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[de.steilerdev.myVerein.server.model.SettingsRepository](https://github.com/steilerDev/myVerein/blob/master/Code/Server/src/main/java/de/steilerdev/myVerein/server/model/SettingsRepository.java) (Retrieving and storing the settings persistent within a properties file, as well as restarting the application if the settings changed)

```
public class SettingsRepository
{
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleMongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private Properties settings;
    private Resource settingsResource;

    private final static String settingsFileName = "myVerein.properties";
    //Property names
    private final static String databaseName = "dbName";
    private final static String databaseHost = "dbHost";
    private final static String databasePort = "dbPort";
    private final static String databaseUser = "dbUser";
    private final static String databasePassword = "dbPassword";
    private final static String rememberMeKey = "rememberMeKey";
    private final static String clubName = "clubName";
    private final static String initSetup = "initSetup";

    private boolean changed;
    private boolean databaseChanged;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SettingsRepository.class);

    public Properties loadSettings() throws IOException
    {
        if(settings == null)
        {
            logger.debug("Loading settings file from classpath");
            settingsResource = new ClassPathResource(settingsFileName);
            changed = false;
            databaseChanged = false;
            return (settings = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(settingsResource));
        } else
        {
            return settings;
        }
    }

    //Getter and setter removed

    public void saveSettings(User currentUser) throws IOException
    {
        saveSettings(loadSettings(), currentUser);
    }

    public void saveSettings(Properties settings, User currentUser) throws IOException
    {
        if(changed)
        {
            logger.debug("Saving settings to " + settingsResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
            settings.store(new FileOutputStream(settingsResource.getFile()), "Settings last changed " + (currentUser != null ? ("by " + currentUser.getEmail() + " (" + LocalDateTime.now().toString() + ")") : LocalDateTime.now().toString()));
            if(databaseChanged)
            {
                try
                {
                    mongoDbFactory.destroy();
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Problem destroying factory");
                }
                ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).refresh();
            }
            this.settings = null;
        } else
        {
            logger.debug("No need to save the settings");
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown in line 178 of the InitController, which means after reloading and during saving an object to the new controller `userRepository.save(superAdmin);`

Comment: Were you able to achieve this Reload/Refresh of spring-data-mongodb ? Could you please share your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say, why reload does not work, based on plain Exception, but here are some hints:

1. Regarding restarting application context, there is a good article

   http://jroller.com/Solomon/entry/reloading_a_spring_web_application

   You can get some clues for why it malfunctions from there.
2. With context reload you need to be careful to close all open resources, properly, on application shutdown.

   Check that you closed Mongo connection properly in your application context.

   [What is the correct way to close the mongo connection using spring-mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721115/what-is-the-correct-way-to-close-the-mongo-connection-using-spring-mongo)

After you added your code. It's hard to understand, what are you trying to accomplish with this. This will take you allot of effort to make it work properly, and most of this efforts will be waist.

You can't reload specific bean in Spring Context, but you can reload whole context, by calling ApplicationContext refresh(), after which all beans will be recreated, including your Controller beans. So this should at least be a separate Controller, with no additional functionality. Also It seems you are assuming you can change mongo configuration, and at the same call write something to mongo, using old references ... this is not how things work in spring. So just don't.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input, unfortunately destroying my template didn't change anything and the first link you provided seems a little bit outdated and to be honest I can't see why the provided functionalities of Spring 4 (`ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh()`) do something different, but I will give it a try as soon as I find the time.

I updated my original question and added some source code of the classes involved, maybe you can give it another try and find my problem using the additional information.

Anyway, thanks for your help!