# Too many threads are already waiting for connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I am using mongodb database. After running my project the initial connections to the mongodb is aroung 21-25, after 5 to 6 hrs connections reached to 230-240 and my application is unable to connect to mongodb. It throws an error saying `Too many threads are already waiting for connection. Max number of threads (maxWaitQueueSize) of 500 has been exceeded.` My application is not able to access any collection from mongodb. To connect to DB we are using two technique one in `spring data JPA` and other is `MongoClient`
I am puzzled up by searching when this is occurring and whats going on. How this many connections are getting created.

Please see the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYVxF.jpg) for error.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why it's required to post a screenshot of the stack trace instead pasting the trace so it can be indexed/searched?

Comment: Have you taken a look at a thread dump and the number of threads that are busy with MongoDB work?

Comment: Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469656/spring-data-mongodb-not-closing-mongodb-connections, it has most relevant info similar to your issue.